# WebStorm huge Parameter Info popup size

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm, parameterinfo

Recently I've noticed that when I use <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> to see parameters in function it creates really huge popup window, but earlier everything was fine

[image]

I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> in a function and it created a huge popup window, but I expected little popup.

Comment: Please *always* state your IDE version. In case you are using some old version and such an issue was fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: I'm using 2022.2

Comment: Try the latest **2023.2** (1 year newer that yours). AFAIK they have changes in this regard. You can install them in parallel if desired (each major version has own folder for the IDE-wide settings), just do not open the same project in both versions at the same time.  https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/ (or via Toolbox App if you are using that to manage your JetBrains IDEs: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/ )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.